# Redux state rerender with useSelector - how to achieve it?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a problem with redux re-render. Or rather lack of it, because using `useState`, everything works perfectly. My question is - how should I use the selector, so once the data is fetched, the component is re-rendered. Also, with redux approach sometimes the object X returns an error of undefined - because the assigned data is not yet fetched. How to overcome this? Should I use `useSelector` in the `useState`? I rather use redux than the local state in this case.], but redux gives me this issue that I am not sure how to overcome.

So I am fetching my data in the useEffect hook. This should also update the redux' state (which it does).

```
useEffect(() => {
    FetchService.fetch()
      .then((res) => dispatch(fetch(res)))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

Then I am grabbing the state using a right selector:

```
const data = useSelector(selectData)
```

At the very end I am assigning this to the object (I cannot skip this, cuz I need it), but sometimes I get an undefined error already here, cuz the data is an empty array):

```
const DATA_TAB_DATASOURCES = {
    dataX: [data],
  };
```

In the component itself I check conditionally if the array isn't undefined, but it seems the problem comes from the selector as with the `useState` it works perfectly as the re-render is automatically triggered with the change.

```
 {data && DATA_TAB_DATASOURCES[dataX].map((c: any, i: number) => 
          .....        

  })}
```

EDIT:

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE: any = {
  data: []
};

export const reducer = (state: any = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH: {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

selector:

```
const globalSelector = (state: any) => state

export const selectData = createSelector(globalSelector, (data) => {
    return data
});
```

Comment: There's not enough code to understand what you're actually doing here. Can you show the _entire_ reducer function, as well as `selectData`?  `useSelector` _will_ force your component to re-render if the selector function returns a new value after a store update.

Comment: @markerikson - the selector works, it grabs the data, but in the object DATA_TAB, it gives sometimes an error, if the selector is still undefined (before the data is fetched) and conditional rendering doesn't seem to prevent it. I added in the EDIT section what you wanted :)

Comment: My console.logs first show undefined, for a brief second, and then, after a second they show correct values, but the app seems cannot see the change in the redux state... dunno why

Comment: Your selector should look like: `export const selectData = state=>state.data` and in render: `{data.length && DATA...`